# How to flush data to Spring data elastic search

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I run this testcase

```
Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
envelope.setId("1");
Envelope saved = envelopeRepository.save(envelope);
assertThat(saved.getId()).isEqualTo("1");
```

saved and envelope are the same object/reference! So even when the index is incorrect, the test still passes! How to fix this issue?

[image]

```
org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient - request [HEAD http://localhost:9200/null?ignore_throttled=false&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open%2Cclosed&allow_no_indices=false]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should the saved entity be a new object? Elasticsearch does not return a document when saving, so there is no need to create a new object here.

What Spring Data Elasticsearch does is update this object with the information returned from the index operation:

- the `id` if it was not already set on the object but was created by Elasticsearch
- version if the entity has a version property
- `seq_no` and `primary_term` if the entity has such a property

If the indexing fails, an exception is thrown.

What do you mean with

> when the index is incorrect

And what has the *HEAD* request do do with this?